# File operation(s) failure on game crash/kill by OS/User in Android

Tags: unity, android

My game saves its state after fixed interval on a file in game/app internal storage. When my game is killed or crashed by user or OS respectively, We write current game state on that file. File writing after fix interval is working fine but when game is crashed/killed by OS or user, file writing operation fails. Operation failure results incomplete game state or empty game state i.e. no data written on file at all. 
I have tried multiple solutions using android service, In case the service is NON STICKY service is killed with the app. On the other hand if service is STICKY then it is restarted but intent that was attached initially with service is null or new one.

The question is that how can i save my data (could be ~2-3MB) completely on file in internal storage when my game/app is killed by user/OS ?

Comment: You gotta handle your SIGTERMs and your SIGKILLs (well maybe not SIGKILLs, Android is probably using SIGTERM). (Don't have time to research / write up a full answer but that's the basic idea.)

Comment: @JohnHamilton SIGKILL can't be handled, by definition.

Comment: @Darkhogg Well, not in Unity, that's for sure. (I did change linux kernel at one point for a project for this specific purpose and it's certainly possible to let programs handle SIGKILL)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would suggest writing your save state in a double-buffered way, as was common for console titles in the past (where you had to cope with the memory card being removed mid-write and writes were slow).

Save:

- If no files exist, write state to file A
- If A exists, write to B
- If A and B both exist, find which one is older, delete it, and then write to that one

Load:

- If both A and B exist, try to load the newer of the two. If that fails (because the file is incomplete or corrupt), delete it and load the other
- If only one exists, load it
- If both are corrupt, inform the user that their save state was irretrievable (like you presumably have to already)

This flow will work to ensure there is always at least one valid save still present in your storage, even if the app is killed mid-write. The player will not get any of the changes in the game state since the previous save if that sort of failure occurs, but they will not have to start again.

In addition, you should be saving immediately after key events (such as in-app purchases) in addition to your interval saving, to minimise the window of vulnerability where a crash/kill would cause that key event to be lost. This is also protection against game exploits (e.g. force-killing the app after losing a life, because you know you'll restore to a game-state from before you lost a life, and get to try again). Of course if do this you must protect your interval saving with logic that says "if a save is already in progress, do not try to start saving again."

Comment: Thanks MrCranky this is partial solution to my problem how can i save data of last session i.e just before killing app/game? For example he made an in app purchase and killed app.

Comment: You don't even need two files. Write to B, if and only if writing was successful, delete A and rename B to A. `java.nio.file.Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)` can do renaming and overwriting as an atomic operation.

Comment: @Polygnome: Note that in the case of power failures this will not always provide the guarantees you expect, unless you call `sync()` on file B before you move it over file A (even then there are not complete guarantees, but `sync()` is fairly good).

Comment: @FaisalImran Save data right after the important operation, for example, after IAP. If the operation was interrupted by phone turning off, I guess it would never take money from the person anyway. But just in case, you might want to save his account data in a purchase on some platform as an attempt to buy something. Then later you can compare your earnings to that data and see if this person really bought something. And then open this feature for him via online service you are using to save all the data. If you are using local saves for IAP, then it's even worse than this problem.

Comment: I'd agree with @CandidMoon, save immediately after the important stuff. If your user is deliberately killing the app immediately after an IAP, they can hardly be surprised if they lose out. The assumption here is that your saves are sensibly short, i.e. <1 second to save. If your saves are taking longer than that, then a) consider optimising what you're saving, and b) consider separating out vital data (like list of IAPs) to a separate file so it can be saved much more quickly and thus be less vulnerable to app being killed mid-write.

Comment: @Polygnome While that's probably neater, managing A and B versions of the files isn't that onerous. If you don't want to have double the storage usage all the time, you can delete the older file as soon as you've confirmed that the newer file is definitely written successfully. This is at its heart a checkpointing problem a la database atomicity; you want as few steps as possible because failure can occur at any step in the process and you have to recover by rolling back to the last viable step. Rolling back itself can fail, so a roll back that involves no operations at all is preferred.

Comment: Lastly, although this may not solve all your problems, I'd say that your problem is not fully solvable. You can't support both "the user may kill my app at any time" and "no data must be lost ever" because there will always be a window after an event has taken place but before it has been persisted to storage where the user can kill the app and lose data.

Comment: Thanks everyone. from all the above discussion i can conclude that i have to divide my  apps data into multiple files. Moreover i cant update/write files on each action, because actions are user dependent and user can fire 10 or more actions in a second. Any suggestions on it ?

Comment: What if i use document database like couchbase. Database can provide me rollback mechanism in case of user kills the app forcefully and transaction isn't completed yet. which solution would be best ?

Comment: As we said above, only save on *important* actions. If you have 10 important actions a second I'd be surprised, but if you do, implement queuing of saves (so if a save is in progress, just flag another save to happen once it's done)
A database solution would achieve the same effect, what I've described is the most basic transactional approach which you can implement easily without the need to refactor what you have into database form. There are some pretty light DB solutions that will work, which is best is not something we can judge here, you have to assess it on your own code.

Answer (score 3):

Android only kills apps when they're in the background. Does your game data really need to be updated when the app is in the background, or can you stop updating the data until the app returns to the foreground? You might be able to defer updates even in a multiplayer game, if you can grab a history of events or even just the current state when the app returns to the foreground. This is something you should probably look at doing anyway for the sake of CPU, network, and battery efficiency.

If the user kills your app, running services should receive a call to `onTaskRemoved`. I don't know what would happen if you tried to do much processing in this method. I expect that if it doesn't return within a certain time, Android will `kill -9` your app.

Comment: app doesn't need be update in background, but app must save its data i.e json file before going to background or destroy.

Comment: you are right onTaskRemoved method will call but the time required to save the file is more or we can say computation time is large. When user kills the app this method will be stoped.